# Adding EditText box to android app based on x,y coordinates?

Tags: android, text, canvas, android-edittext

I am looking to be able to first detect touch events to draw a box whatever size the user wants on the canvas - this part I have completed.

I then need to take the coordinates of that box and create a edittext box in its place. Any Suggestions ? I would then like to make the text entered become part of the canvas itself, no longer editable any ideas there either ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `AbsoluteLayout` and add touch listener via [`setOnTouchListener(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29)

Then when touch happens, detect the location and add `EditText` via

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
    new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT, x, y);
absoluteLayout.addView(editText, layoutParams);
```

Comment: I tried what you said, and although it would work, it says absoluteLayout has been depreceated and I should use a custom layout instead, I am currently looking into this, any expertise in this area ?